# concat vs push in react js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am pretty new to React. I am not understanding why is this issue not working.
I have `Numbers Component`.

```
const Numbers = (props) => {
  return(
    <div className="card text-center">
        <div>
        {Numbers.list.map((num,i) => 
            <span key={i} onClick={() => props.selectNumbers(num)}>
            {num}
          </span>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

Numbers.list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
```

Now in the parent `Game` component ..

```
class Game extends React.Component {

    state = {
    selectedNumbers : []
  };

  selectNumber = (clickedNumber) => {
    if(this.state.selectedNumbers.indexOf(clickedNumber) >= 0) {return;}
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        selectedNumbers: prevState.selectedNumbers.concat(clickedNumber)
    }));
  };


    render() {
    const {selectedNumbers } = this.state;
    return (
        <div className="container">
        <h3>
            Play Nine
        </h3>
        <hr />
        <div className="row">
          <Answer selectedNums = {selectedNumbers} />
        </div>
        <br />
        <Numbers selectNumbers={this.selectNumber} selectedNums = {selectedNumbers} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Now, this thing works fine. But when I do ...

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
        selectedNumbers: prevState.selectedNumbers.push(clickedNumber)
    }));
```

the application does work as expected.

`As prevState.selectedNumbers is an array` should not it be `push` rather than `concat`?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: push is a mutating operation. So calling push on the previous state would try to mutate it. It's like trying to change history. What you want to do is create a new state by reusing the old state without mutating it. That's what you can do with concat or the ES6 spread operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `push`, you are setting `selectedNumbers` to be the return value of the push operation, which is the length of the new array according to the [mozilla developer docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).  Push also attempts to mutate the array in state, which as PhilippSpo said doesn't work.

Either use `concat` as you were before or copy the `selectedNumbers` to a new array, push your value into that one, and then set `selectedNumbers` to the new array.  If you're using ES6 you can use the spread operator as other users have pointed out

Answer (score 5):

In few words:

> [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) adds an element into original array and returns an **integer** which is its new array `length`.
>
> [`Array.prototype.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) returns a **new array** with concatenated element without even touching in original array. It's a shallow copy.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) is a mutating function and returns the length of the resulting array. You can use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to easily push a new item.

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
        selectedNumbers: [...prevState.selectedNumbers, clickedNumber]
    }));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use **concat()** function in place of **push()** because react does not work good with object mutability react people emphasize react developers to keep the state of immutable.

When you use **concat()** function it always returns a new object rather than mutating the same old object that is why you should never use **push()** function in react because push mutates the old object.